# Is there any problem with this implementation of the Merge Sort algorithm?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, mergesort

I know there are many implementations of the merge sort algorithm. I have implemented the following code according to the algorithm provided in the book *Introduction to Algorithms* by CLRS.

```
void merge_sort(int arr[], int starting_index, int ending_index) {  

    if(starting_index < ending_index) {         

        int middle_index = (starting_index + ending_index)/2;
        merge_sort(arr, starting_index, middle_index);  
        merge_sort(arr, middle_index+1, ending_index);
        merge_the_parts(arr, starting_index, middle_index, ending_index);   
    }
}

void merge_the_parts(int arr[], int starting_index, int middle_index, int ending_index) {

    int length_of_first_array = middle_index - starting_index + 1;
    int length_of_second_array = ending_index - middle_index;

    const int sentinel = INT_MAX;

    int left_arr[length_of_first_array + 1]; 
    int right_arr[length_of_second_array + 1]; 

    for(int i=0; i<length_of_first_array; i++) {
        left_arr[i] = arr[starting_index + i];      
    }

    // building second auxilliary
    for(int i=0; i<length_of_second_array; i++) {
        right_arr[i] = arr[(middle_index+1) + i];
    }

    left_arr[length_of_first_array] = sentinel; // use the sentinel as a condition
    right_arr[length_of_second_array] = sentinel;

    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    // the main merging loop
    for(int k=starting_index; k<ending_index+1; k++) {

        if(left_arr[i] <= right_arr[j]) {
            arr[k] = left_arr[i];
            i++;
        }

        else {
            arr[k] = right_arr[j];
            j++;
        }
    }   
}
```

The code works fine for sorting the array and inversion count. But it gives the wrong answer to this problem - https://www.spoj.com/problems/DCEPC206/. I have used the following code for the problem.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <climits>
using namespace std;

long int merge(int *arr, int l, int mid, int r) {

    int n1 = mid - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - mid;

    int *arrL = new int[n1 + 1];
    int *arrR = new int[n2 + 1];

    for(int i=0; i<n1; i++) {
        arrL[i] = arr[l + i];
    }

    for(int j=0; j<n2; j++) {
        arrR[j] = arr[(mid + 1) + j];
    }

    arrL[n1] = INT_MAX;
    arrR[n2] = INT_MAX;

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    long int count = 0;

    for(int k=l; k<=r; k++) {

        if(arrL[i] < arrR[j]) {
            arr[k] = arrL[i];
            if(arrR[j] != INT_MAX) {
                count += (arrL[i] * (n2 - j));
            }
            i++;
        } else {
            arr[k] = arrR[j];
            j++;
        }
    }

    delete[] arrL;
    delete[] arrR;

    return count;
}

long int countSeries(int *arr, int l, int r) {

    long int count = 0;

    if(l < r) {

        int mid = (l + r) / 2;
        count += countSeries(arr, l, mid);
        count += countSeries(arr, mid + 1, r);
        count += merge(arr, l, mid, r);
        return count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: You answered your question yourself, there is a problem. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to help you write more useful questions. Also, extract and provide a [mcve], which includes enough info to reproduce the failure.

Comment: The code could be changed to check indexes for reaching the end of a sub-array, rather than relying on sentinel (INT_MAX) values. If the data can never contain sentinel values, it's not an issue. The code could be sped up by doing a one time allocation of a working array, and changing the direction of merge based on level of recursion (or switch to bottom up merge sort, and change direction of merge based on loop count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting wrong answer because you're using just a `long` to hold such large value of `count` considering the ranges given in the problem.

Use `long long` which can hold the large value and not overflow:

`long long count = 0;`,
`long long countSeries(int *arr, int l, int r) {`,
`count += (long long)arrL[i] * (n2 - j);`

[Here's a running code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ucRAnT94g96A9hro)